# Non-geodesic circular orbit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, acceleration

From N. Straumann, *General Relativity*

> Exercise 4.9: Calculate the radial acceleration for a non-geodesic circular orbit in the Schwarzschild spacetime. Show that this becomes *positive* for $r>3GM$. This counter-intuitive result has led to lots of discussions.

This is one of those problems where I have absolutely no clue what to do. Since it says non-geodesic, I can't use any of the usual equations. I don't know what equation to solve. *Maybe* I solve $\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma=f$ with $f$ some force that makes $\gamma$ non-geodesic. But I don't know where to go from there if that's the way to do it.

Also any specific links to discussions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: So I tried solving $\nabla_u u=f$ with the constraints $\theta=\pi/2$, $u^\theta=0$ and $u^r=0$. lionelbrits has explained I must also add $\dot u^r=0$ to my list. This all leads to 
$$(r_S-2Ar)(u^\varphi)^2+\frac{r_S}{r^2}=f^r$$
($A=1-r_S/r$, notation is standard Schwarzschild) The problem with this is that the $u^\varphi$ term is *negative* for $r>3m$. So somewhere a sign got screwed up and for the life of me I don't know where it is. A decent documentation of my work: http://www.texpaste.com/n/a6upfhqo, http://www.texpaste.com/n/dugoxg4a.

Comment: You can find a general path with $\dot r = 0, \theta = \pi/2$.  Then, yes, you just calculate that acceleration term.

Comment: correct.  Any curve should have unit length.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer   What do I do about the $2\Gamma^r_{tt}(u^t)^2$ term? I'm not sure what $u^t$ is in a non-geodesic prescription. ⟨u,u⟩=−1 still holds, right?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer What I have so far: http://www.texpaste.com/n/a6upfhqo. I feel like I should be able to express $(u^t)^2$ in terms of $(u^\varphi)^2$ using $\langle u,u\rangle=-1$, right?

Comment: Yes, you solve for $u^t$ in terms of $u^\varphi$ using the norm of the velocity vector being -1. Basically this just means that you have suitably chosen an affine parameter.

Comment: @lionelbrits Ok, I think I'm close now: http://www.texpaste.com/n/dugoxg4a

Comment: I want to say $\dot u^r = 0$...

Comment: @lionelbrits But the question statement says it is positive.

Comment: First, proper acceleration is not the same as $\dot u^r$. Second, by radial acceleration, do they mean centripetal? There is a radial acceleration inwards when you move in a circle, even when $r$ is fixed.

Comment: I would assume by radial acceleration the radial component of acceleration is meant. I'm assuming this is centripetal, hence why I set $u^r=0$. By proper acceleration do you mean $dr/dt$?

Comment: If $u^r = 0$ as a fact, then $\dot u^r = 0$, also.

Comment: @lionelbrits Calculus doesn't work that way. A ball bas zero velocity at the top of its path but always has 9.8 m/s^s acceleration. Or in GR, $\Gamma=0$ in a normal coordinate system but $\text{Riem}\sim\partial \Gamma\ne0$. How would you answer the problem then? I posted the full question.

Comment: A circular orbit has $r = \mathrm{const}$. No matter how  many derivatives of $r$ you take with respect to $\tau$, zero you will get. I suggest that you factor your workings into your question because it is one vote away from being closed (I would personally keep it open).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19233/discussion-between-0celo7-and-lionelbrits).

Answer (score 2):

The equivalence principle tells us that we can evaluate $\nabla_u u$ in a co-moving reference frame and that for geodesics we should find no acceleration (to the occoupants of an elevator in free-fall, the contents seem to be experiencing no acceleration). Therefore, if we evaluate this when we are not along a geodesic (elevator sitting on earth), we find that it is not zero. Because it is a vector, if it is non-zero in one frame, it must be non-zero in another. In other words, yes, $f^r$ is what you have to calculate. The ingredient that you are missing is that $r=\mathrm{const}$ for a circular orbit implies that $\dot{u}^r = 0$. This is not a local thing, it is simply because you are forcing the orbit to be circular.

Comment: So by doing this in http://www.texpaste.com/n/dugoxg4a I get $0=-r_S(u^\varphi)^2-\frac{r_S}{r^2}+2Ar(u^\varphi)^2+f^r$. I think I screwed up a sign because when I rearrange to get $\frac{r_S}{r^2}+(u^\varphi)^2(r_S-2Ar)=f^r$, it is actually negative for $r>3m$. Any idea what's up?

Comment: Is that a covariant/contravariant issue?

Comment: You haven't defined $A$ yet.

Comment: I don't think so. $r_S-2Ar=6m-2r$. Obviously this is negative when it should be positive. On the other hand this is not a simple overall sign flip because the term $r_S/r^2$ is positive when it should be. So $f^r$ can either be positive *or* negative depending on $(u^\varphi)^2$ and $m$ it seems.

Comment: $A$ is defined in the OP and in the links in the above discussion.

Comment: $r_s - 2 A r = r_s - 2r + 2 r_s$. Your units look screwy but I'm not sure what $u^\varphi$ is. In any case, $(u^\varphi)$ must be positive because you are squaring it. Nevermind, you meant the factor multiplying that term.

Comment: $r_S=2m$ ($m=GM$), so $r_S-2Ar=6m-2r$. $u^\varphi$ is the $\varphi$ component of velocity, which ought to be a constant of motion. Yes, I am also concerned about the units.